# Please correct my loop to check if a string contains vowels (Python)?

Tags: python, string, contains

I typed the following to check if a string contains vowels, but seems to have something wrong as it reports first letter to be non-vowel for the whole word.

What should I do?

```
def vowel(s):
    s = str(s)
    s = s.lower()
    vowel = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
    for char in s:
        if char in vowel:
            print("Yes,", s, "contains a vowel.")
            break
        else:
            print("No,", s, "has no vowels contained.")
            break

vowel("apple")
vowel("shh")
```

Comment: @ch2019. What's unclear? OP shows how the code is called, and explains expected vs actual outputs. This is a beginner question for sure, but definitely a complete and well posed one.

Comment: Well, after the first character, you call `break` regardless whether that character is a vowel or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop `breaks` on the first character no matter what. You can say that the word has a vowel if the first character is a vowel, but you can't say it doesn't until you've reached the end. Python has a neat construct that's made exactly for this purpose: the `for`-loop `else` clause. This only gets triggered if you reach the end of a loop without breaking out.

So you can fix your code by deleting 8 spaces and a `break`.

```
def vowel(s):
    s = str(s)
    s = s.lower()
    vowel = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
    for char in s:
        if char in vowel:
            print("Yes,", s, "contains a vowel.")
            break
    else:
        print("No,", s, "has no vowels contained.")

vowel("apple")
vowel("shh")
```

To optimise this, consider using the built-in function `any` in addition to the operator `in`. You can write `vowel` as a single string and check for containment in that directly:

```
if any(char in 'aeiou' for char in s):
    print("Yes,", s, "contains a vowel.")
else:
    print("No,", s, "contains no vowels.")
```

You could even rewrite the condition as

```
any(map('aeiou'.__contains__ s))
```

For containment checks, it's often more efficient to use a `set` to achieve `O(1)` lookup, but the sequence of vowels is so small I doubt it'll be much slower to just use the default linear search of `str.__contains__`.

For some very rare cases, like strings of fewer than 5 chars or so, you could reverse the check:

```
any(map(s.__contains__, 'aeiou'))
```

Comment: Thank you MP! What would be the concise experienced way to do this? I know mine is longer and more beginners like.

Comment: Thank you very much, you respond very fast!

Comment: @Scoutboy84. I happened to look right as you posted your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def vowel(s):
    s = str(s)
    s = s.lower()
    vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")

    for vowel in vowels:
        if vowel in s:
            print("Yes,", s, "contains a vowel.")
            return True

    print("No,", s, "does not contain a vowel.")
    return False
```

This would be one way of doing it. As soon as a vowel has been found the function returns True thus stops the search. If no vowel is found, the loop terminates and the 'No' statement is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `if-else` within the `for-loop` you can rather just have an `if` to check if a vowel was found. If a vowel was found then print “found” and `return` from the function. If a vowel was not found that means the `for-loop` has ended and you can then just print “not found”:

```
def vowel(s):
    s = str(s)
    s = s.lower()
    vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

    for char in s:
        if char in vowel:
            print("Yes,", s, "contains a vowel.")
            return
    print("No,", s, "has no vowels contained.")
```

If you want to count how many of each vowels were found you can use a dictionary:

```
    vowel = {"a":0, "e":0, "i":0, "o":0, "u":0}
```